# JSONArray within JSONArray

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm currently confused why I cannot pull a JSONArray from a JSONArray in my android application. An example and a snippet of my source code are given below.

```
//The JSON

   {
     "currentPage":1,
     "data":[
        {
          "id":"dimtrs",
          "name":"Bud Light",
          "breweries":[
              {
                "id":"BznahA",
                "name":"Anheuser-Busch InBev",
              }
           ]
        }
    ],
    "status":"success"
  }
```

Now I'm trying to retreive the "breweries" array.

```
//Code Snippet

...

JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(inputLine);

JSONArray jArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");

JSONArray jsArray = jArray.getJSONArray("breweries");

...
```

I can pull objects out of the data array just fine, but I cannot get the "breweries" array from the "data" array using my current code.

The error for jsArray is:

> The method .getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments String

So what is the correct way to pull the "breweries" array out of the "data" array?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Just a thought, but the breweries needs to be inside `{ }` doesn't it? So you have something like: `{ "breweries":[ {"id":"BznahA","name":"Anheuser-Busch InBev"}] }`

Comment: The JSON you show is invalid, therefore no, there isn't a way to parse it. You can use [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to see this is the case.

Comment: Well you get that error obviously because the method needs the index value as int, and you are passing the string value. The other problem as mentioned is that the JSON in not in the correct format, but anyways you cant use jArray.getJSONArray("breweries"); If you want to use something like that, you need to convert the value to a JSONObject.

Comment: I apologize, I shortened the JSON I was receiving and had a mistype. The edited JSON should be correct now. Thanks!

Comment: After editing the JSON and realizing that I had an error in the toy example I was working with to code, its easily seen where I went wrong. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because "breweries" is in the 1st object of the "data" array, not directly on the array itself. You are trying to get a key from an array.

So you want to call `jArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("breweries");` or something to that effect.

As Sambhav Sharma explains in a comment, the reason for the error is that get methods for JSONArray expect an int and not a String as their argument.

Comment: Haha yes, after I edited my toy JSON correctly I realized this. Thanks!